# Redireccionar este Route cuando el usuario está logueado y es su tipo correctamente en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

No se muy bien como redireccionar a mi usuario cuando está logueado desde la página principal.

La autentificación la he creado con:

> - composer require laravel/ui
> - php artisan ui:auth

[He seguido este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9PNmtB5Cf0) para que lo consulteis si necesitais más información.

Al iniciar sesión se le redirige con esta funcion en Logincontroller que he añadido posteriormente:

```
 public function redirectPath()
        {
            if(Auth::user()->tipo_usuario){ //si administrador es true
                return '/users'; //cambiar ruta por la de gestion de usuarios
            }
            return '/';
        }
```

Es decir si el tipo de usuario es 1 redirige a la dirección de /users pero si es 0 que es otro tipo de usuario lo redirige a la página principal.

yo he tratado de modificar un poco este código, que se ha generado al crearlo y he añadido este trozo de código de views/Layout/app.blade.php en mi barra de navegación donde está mi web de esta forma al usuario le sale una llave si no está logueado y si está logueado le aparece su nombre y la opción de desconectarse.

```
@guest
    <!-- si no esta logueado se muestra una llave a la página de login-->
    <a title="login" href="{{ url('/login') }}" target="_self" id="enlaceLogin"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></a>
    @else
    <!-- si esta logueado se muestra el nombre o salir de sesion-->
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>

    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        {{ __('Salir') }}
    </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
        @csrf
    </form>
    @endguest
```

Hasta aquí bién, pero que pasa que si pulsamos el nombre del usuario logueado le lleva a la dirección # que es la que hay puesta como enlace al clicar el nombre. a mi me gustaría que hiciera la misma función que cuando un usuario se loguea, es decir si pulsamos el nombre te lleva a tu página asignada si eres 1 o 0 depende de tu tipo de usuario para ello he intentado lo siguiente:

En la barra de navegacion he colocado:

> href="{{ route('login') }}"

```
<!-- si esta logueado se muestra el nombre o salir de sesion-->
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{{ route('login') }}" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
```

Tratando de ver si hacía el mismo efecto que cuando un usuario se loguea. He tratado también de colocar un formulario similar al de cuando pulsamos el boton de login en :

> resources/vies/auth/login.blade.php

Pero sin mucho exito tampoco, he pensado que modificar el archivo de HomeController.php en http/controllers cambiando el index por defecto que te devuelve a la vista home por esto otro igual que en LoginController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->tipo_usuario){ //si administrador es true
            return view('/users'); //cambiar ruta por la de gestion de usuarios
        }
        return view('/');
    }
```

Parece que funciona per al tratar de entrar en la ruta indicada sale el siguiente error si eres tipo 0:

> - InvalidArgumentException
> - View [.] not found.

Si eres del tipo 1 aparece este error

> - InvalidArgumentException
> - View [.users] not found.

Por lo tanto nose si estoy equivocada he llegado a la conclusión de que el problema está en la ruta.

Así que me he dirigido a Routes/web.php  y he tratado de modificar:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Por:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

O tal vez sea algo similar, pero nose muy bien como hacerlo correctamente, ya que segun he visto el index de la ruta es la función de HomeController por lo tanto nose muy bien como hacer esta ruta adecuadamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las vistas son los archivos blade. En ningún caso empiezan con `/`. Y por eso el error que te aparece es:

> View [.] not found

En el caso que lo tengas en `resources/views` y el archivo se llame `users.blade.php` debes indicar tu función como:

```
return view('users');
```

En el caso de que lo tengas en una subcarpeta como: `resources/views/admin/especial/tablero/ultima_version.blade.php`.
Debes indicarlo como:

```
return view('admin.especial.tablero.ultima_version');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ya lo he arreglado, desconocia este dato